# Склонение ЧОП

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли "Общество с ограниченной ответственностью Частное охранное предприятие"?

Answer (score 1):

Привели бы Вы конкретный пример. А то все время приходится додумывать. Если это разговорная ситуация, то, наверное, скажут просто: я работаю в охране. Или в ЧОПе (если такое сокращение где-то в ходу, я не знаю).  Или, например, " в ООО "Частное охранное предприятие" произошли структурные изменения - если это официальная ситуация.